# package ‘RHTMLForms’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3) - tried most online suggestions

Tags: r, install.packages

I need to install `RHTMLForms`.
Based on suggestions elsewhere, so far I tried:

- manually specifying repo: install.packages("RHTMLForms", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type = "source")
- mentioning method, both "curl", "wget"
- running : options(download.file.method = "wget") before install.packages
- using R from terminal

Nothing seems to work. Will somebody please help to suggest what might be wrong? 
If possibly the repo is outdated (here, omegahat.org) how to find other way to download this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `devtools`?

```
if(!require("devtools"))
  install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("omegahat/RHTMLForms")
```

This works fine for me!

Comment: Thanks. It did work for me. But apparently there was also problem with curl and xml libraries. So after lot of looking around running these following commands before your solution worked for me:  `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`
`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`